# convert time stamp to Date inside angular expression like {{new Date(timestamp)}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today I found that's it's not working to convert for a date inside angular expression.

So I just making something like

```
<th>{{new Date(elem.timestamp}}</th>
```

But it fails with internal angular error.

So why it's not possible to cast to Date inside angular expression?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because angular expressions do not accept arbitrary Javascript code, including creating new objects. What you are looking for is called angular filters, they were specifically designed for this case.

So instead of

```
{{new Date(elem.timestamp)}}
```

you should write

```
{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

More info on the date filter can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). More on filters, in general, can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: could you provide a link to docs where said that arbitrary code not accepted? I looking for that for a short time, but not found it.

Comment: <th>{{(new Date(elem.timestamp)).getFullYear}}</th>

Comment: My date is comming like this DateTime : "2017/12/15" but doing this {{M.DateTime | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}} not changing date format.

Answer (score 20):

If you are dealing with Firebase Timestamp object (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp), you can use:

```
{{elem.timestamp.seconds*1000 | date}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an extention of what @package mentioned we can also go to hour-second as well from millisecond, the format can be any pattern as well

```
< th >{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a'}}< /th >
```

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with Firebase timestamp I use :

```
{{ element.seconds * 1000| date:'short' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use a library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/) for this.  Also the functionality you are looking for is meant to be implemented via "[filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)"

Also see [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

Answer (score 1):

When the timestamp is in milliseconds:
Only Date:

```
{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Date & Time:

```
{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a'}}
```

Date & Time(24-hr format):

```
{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

When your timestamp is in seconds, then just multiply with 1000:

```
{{elem.timestamp*1000 | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working to convert for a date inside an Angular expression.

So I just making something like:

```html
{{elem.timestamp | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```