# Angularfire2 Get Time

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database has this type of time [image]

Then I want to show that time in front view like this ( 6.00 AM.. etc).I retrieve Rides details already. When I search about this I got some idea about `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but I have no idea how to apply it with my code.

**Component.ts**

```
getRides(){
   this.ridesService.getRidesByRideID(rideId).subscribe(response => {
      this.activeridesList.push({
        rideDetails : response,
      });
    });
};
```

**Edit**

I already take value from database like ,  `' departure-timestamp: 1535520712696 '` .I want to convert that time like `' 6.00 AM '` .So I use **Moment.js**. In my front end I use `'  {{ (activeRide.rideDetails.departure-timestamp | amFromUnix) | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}} '` but it's not work.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time/34719492

Comment: I already take value like this,  ' departure-timestamp: 1535520712696 ' .I want to convert that time like ' 6.00 AM ' .So I use Moment.js. In my front end I use '  {{ (activeRide.rideDetails.departure-timestamp | amFromUnix) | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}} ' but it's not work.

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: I refer this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848407/convert-time-stamp-to-date-inside-angular-expression-like-new-datetimestamp) . change my Front End code => `{{activeRide.rideDetails.departure-timestamp | date:" h:mma"}}` but nothing show .But when I use put time in manually like this `{{'1535520712696' | date:" h:mma"}}` then it's work.